# SwiftUI Navigation Link Selection's Highlight Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

In iOS, **when you tap a row** in a list to navigation to a page, **the row gets highlighted** to indicate which row is selected. This is not working for me when I have a `NavigationStack(path:root:)` that uses `NavigationLink(_ titleKey:value:)` and `navigationDestination(for:destination)`.

**Highlight doesn't work** in the code below for me neither in Simulator nor device:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExperimentView: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            List {
                NavigationLink("Page", value: 0)
                NavigationLink("Page", value: 1)
                NavigationLink("Page", value: 2)
            }
            .navigationTitle("List")
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { int in
                Text(int.description)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it works just fine when I use `NavigationStack(root:)` that uses `NavigationLink(_ titleKey:destination)`.

Comment: Can you describe more specifically how "the row gets highlighted"? I don't see any difference between using `.init(_:destination:)` and `.inti(_:value)`. The navigation links turn grey when I tap on them in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the core differences between `NavigationStack` and `NavigationSplitView`.

The `selection` only works with `NavigationSplitView` I assume it is because the `List` does not stay on the screen with `NavigationStack`

```
struct ExperimentView: View {
    @State private var selection: Int?
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                NavigationLink("Page", value: 0)
                NavigationLink("Page", value: 1)
                NavigationLink("Page", value: 2)
            }
        } detail: {
            if let selection {
                Text(selection.description)

            } else {
                Text("Please select page.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types#Update-selection-based-navigation